# The units of spatial frequency of fft

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

We are performing fft on N samples of a function f(x) that is periodic on the interval [0,L] where x is in meters. What would be the most common definition of the units of the domain of  the transformed signal ?  Will it be cycles per meter or radians per meter ?

Comment: What is fft in full name?

Comment: Fast Fourier Transform